# How to return values after post in Jquery from the view to the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in Telerik Grid.

My code for Grid - Onload is:

```
function OnLoad(e)
{
    //$("#userSecurityGrid").data("tGrid").pageSize = 50;
    $.post("@Url.Action("SetGridPageSize", "UserSecurity")")
}
```

My controller code looks like:

```
[GridAction]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public int SetGridPageSize()
{
    // to get grid page size value from table
    // return value;
}
```

In the controller I will get the value from the table and I have to return to set the Page size.

I can set the grid page size value by

```
$("#userSecurityGrid").data("tGrid").pageSize
```

But, My question is that how I can return the value from the "SetGridPageSize" controller to the function "OnLoad" to assign the grid page size value.
Provide me a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pick up the return value and set pageSize in the $.post callback:

```
function OnLoad(e)
{
    $.post("@Url.Action("SetGridPageSize", "UserSecurity")", function(data) {
        $("#userSecurityGrid").data("tGrid").pageSize = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Working as expected. Great.